# Sonarqube showing class not found error when building a multi module project

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I have a multi module project, and when I run Sonarqube task it shows

```
Could not find class xxx.xxx.xxx, due to: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: yyy/xxx/zzz
```

error.

Which is due to I use providedCompile instead of compile in gradle which cause the class source that has dependencies on another module to not compiled into build/classes/main folder.

Is there a way to point the source or copy the source over to that particular module?